# How can I make `file -i` command return ISO-8859-9?

Tags: linux, vim, encoding, character-encoding, vi

Let's say I have a text file with content

```
şşş
```

and in `vi/vim` I have set `fileencoding` as `:set fileencoding=ISO-8859-9`.

Later when I check the encoding with

`file -i <myFile>`

it gives `text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1` although it *should have been* `ISO-8859-9`.

**Why is that? How can I make `file -i` return `ISO-8859-9`?**

Because otherwise when I reopen the file in `vi/vim` it assumes encoding `ISO-8859-1` and shows wrong characters:

```
þþþþþþþþþþ
```

Comment: You need to look at the `'fileencodings'` option, too. Set your preferred before others.

Comment: @Heptite it only helps to set correct encoding for `vim`. it doesn't solve my original question which is *How can I make file -i return ISO-8859-9*

Comment: I've tried to look into it, but from what I can see it's unlikely the `file` utility can (reliably) distinguish between the `ISO-8859-*` encodings. Do you have the option of going `UTF8` instead?

Comment: @Heptite if only I could use `utf8` but there is a database on which I don't have any authority and it only accepts `iso-8859-9`